# Matrix Class in C++: An Explanation

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, matrix

I am currently browsing over some old college snippets of c++ code. Back then, one of the other class was assigned with doing a matrix class using double pointers and 2D arrays. Luckily (or unluckily upon hindsight) I never did get a chance to learn stuff like that. I borrowed their code when we graduated for future review. If anyone can please explain to me what exactly happens in this snippet:

```
  //This is a constructor of a 1x1 matrix
  signal::signal(){
     _nrows = 1;
     _ncols = 1;
     _coef = new double*[_nrows];
     _coef[0] = new double[_ncols];
     _coef[0][0] = 0.0;
  }
```

Just a sidenote, _coef is a ** of type double.

From what I understand, _nrows and _ncols are given a value of 1 (meaning their sizes). Then, the code dynamically creates a double* out in the heap with elements equal to _nrows; the problem is, I dont exactly know what happens next. Why is the array corresponding to _ncols not a pointer? Why is it assigned _coef[0]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In memory, a two dimensional array (n, m) looks more or less like this

```
_coef -> | _coef[0] -> {1, 2, 3, ..., m}
         | _coef[1] -> {1, 2, 3, ..., m}
         | _coef[2] -> {1, 2, 3, ..., m}
         | ...
         | _coef[n] -> {1, 2, 3, ..., m}
```

`_coef` points to an array of `n` pointers. And each of these pointers point to an array of `m` doubles.

So, in your case `_coef` points to an array of 1 pointer and this pointer points to an array of one double.

Now to your questions

1. It is not a pointer, because in your second dimension, you finally want to store the doubles, not pointers.
2. It is assigned to `_coef[0]`, because it is the first, and only, row of your two dimensional array.

Answer (score 1):

The first two lines, as you say, assign the value `1` to each of `_nrows` and `_ncols`.

The following line dynamically allocates an array of `double*` (pointers to `double`). The number of `double*` objects allocated is `_nrows` (which is `1` in your case). Think of that syntax as similar to defining a normal automatic array, `double* array[1]`, where the number of elements is `1`. Then `_coef` is a pointer to the first of those `double` pointers. I'll represent the memory representation diagrammatically:

```
_nrows = 1
_ncols = 1
_coef  ---> _coef[0] ---> Currently points nowhere in particular
```

So now you have `_nrows` amount of `double*` lined up in memory. `_coef[0]` refers to the first of those `double*`. A new dynamically allocated array, this time of `double`s, is created of size `_ncols`. A pointer to the first of those `double`s is assigned to `_coef[0]`. That is, the first `double*` in the first dynamically allocated array now points to the first `double` in the second dynamically allocated array.

```
_nrows = 1
_ncols = 1
_coef  ---> _coef[0] ---> _coef[0][0]
```

Then `_coef[0][0] = 0.0` sets the first `double` in the second dynamically allocated array to `0`. Since it's the *only* `double`, because the sizes of both of your dynamically allocated arrays are `1`, you have initialized all `double`s to 0.

```
_nrows = 1
_ncols = 1
_coef  ---> _coef[0] ---> _coef[0][0] = 0
```

Comment: This was also very helpful as well!